# How to sum up the values of table column including all pages of a paged result using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to get the value of a html table including pagination results using javascript?`    Total

```
    <td class="center" id="col_sum_ps_total"></td>
    <td class="center" id="col_sum_ps_total"></td>
    <td class="center" id="col_sum_bo_total"></td>
    <td class="center" id="col_sum_ao_total"></td>
    <td class="center" id="col_sum_p_total"></td>

    <td class="center"></td>
    <td class="center"></td>
    <td class="center"></td>
    <td class="center"></td>
    <td class="center"></td>    `
```

Comment: Please define *"value of a HTML table"*.

Comment: **Unclear info** . Also **id** is unique per page. Keep it in mind.

Comment: Could you please add a little more description about the problem you have?

Comment: I have a four page html table integer value results. I need to get the sum of a column in this table..By using javascript i can get the sum of a column with the values present in a present page only. I can't get the values from all the four pages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way here is that you compute the sum on the server side and include it with each paged result.

You have not provided information on how your page is rendered - whether it is rendered via server side templating or by changing the data using AJAX. Either way you will get the paged data including hopefully including some meta information like how many rows there are in total, how many pages, which page is currently selected etc. So to that meta information you could add the property that contains the sum of that column.

If you really have no way to change the server, you would have to query all the pages using AJAX/XHR and compute the sum on the client side - but if you do that then you can skip the whole paging thing and simply show everything at once as you are fetching it anyway.

Comment: I get the column value from database and displayed using .tpl file.Also i edit that values  and saved to db using javascript and Ajax. So I think i need to compute it in client side...right.?

Comment: No, provide it in the `.tpl` file (that is server side template). Create a backend method that queries the DB for it using aggregation (`SELECT sum(col) FROM table;` or such), if necessary. This could be documented as part of the framework you are using (the one that renders your `.tpl` files). If there is decent documentation for it. Do not do it on the client side if you have access to the server.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, Risadinha..
But i need to change the values in column also.
So after change the value..How could be the sum will appear.

Comment: Keep track of the changes and subtract/add them to the sum via JS. But that doesn't mean you have to sum all of it up with JS, as well.